# Move all files from subdirectory into a new directory without overwriting

Tags: macos, bash, random, rename, mv

I want to consolidate into 1 directory files that are in multiple subdirectories.

The following comes close except that the random string is added after the extension; I want it before the extension:

```
find . -type f -iname "[a-z,0-9]*" -exec bash -c 'mv -v "$0" "./$( mktemp "$( basename "$0" ).XXX" )"' '{}' \;
```

I've searched through dozens of other posts but nothing addressed the specifics of my situation:

- I'm on OS X (so it's a BSD flavor of Bash; for ex. there's no -t option for mv)
- Many of the files have identical names so I need to rewrite them during the mv (and I can't just use the -n option for mv because there too many files would thus not get moved)
- The files are not all the same kind, so I need to use a `find -type f`
- I want to exclude .DS_store files, so it seems like a good option is `find -type f -iname "[a-z,0-9]*"`
- I want the rewritten files's names to be in the form of: oldname-random_string.xyz (but I'm also OK with having the files being renamed as a sequential list: 00001.xyz, 00002.xyz, etc.)
- The files are buried 4 levels down from my master directory:

  - Master/Top dir
  - Dir 2
  - Dir 3
  - Dir 4
  - Dir 5
  - file
- For the sake of simplicity I prefer a bash command to a .sh script (but I'm happy with either)

Comment: doesn't the OS X command 'ditto' do what you want?

Comment: Does it have to be command line? What about trying AppleScript/Automator?

Comment: Finally, I think this question probably belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### GNU Solution

This uses basically the same command that you were using but I supply a template to `mktemp` so that the `XXX` pattern appears just before the suffix.  With GNU `sed`:

```sh
find . -type f -iname "[a-z,0-9]*" -exec bash -c 'mv -v "$1" "./$(mktemp -u "$(basename "$1" | sed -E -e '\''s/\.([^.]+)$/.XXX.\1/'\'' -e '\''/XXX/ !s/$/.XXX/'\'')" )"' _ '{}' \;
```

The key addition above is the use of `sed` to insert `XXX` before the suffix in the file name:

```
sed -E -e 's/\.([^.]+)$/.XXX.\1/' -e '/XXX/ !s/$/.XXX/'
```

This has two commands.  The first puts `.XXX` before the extension.  The second command is run only if the file name has no extension in which case it adds `.XXX` to the end of the file name.

In the first command, the source regex consists of two parts.  The first is `\.` which matches a period.  The second is `([^.]+)$` which captures the extension into group 1.  The substitution replaces this with `.XXX.\1` where `\1` is `sed` notation for group 1 which, in our case, is the file's extension.

#### OSX Solution

Under OSX, `mktemp` is not useful because it only supports templates with the XXX part trailing.  As a workaround, we can use a bash script that generates non-overlapping file names:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -type f -iname "[a-z,0-9]*" -print0 |
while IFS= read -r -d '' fname
do
    new=$(basename "$fname")
    [ "$fname" = "./$new" ] && continue
    [ "$new" = .DS_store ] && continue
    name=${new%.*}
    ext=${new#"$name"}
    n=0
    new=$(printf '%s.%03i%s' "$name" "$n" "$ext")
    while [ -f "$new" ]
    do
        n=$(($n + 1))
        new=$(printf '%s.%03i%s' "$name" "$n" "$ext")
    done
    mv -v "$fname" "$new"
done
```

The above uses the `find` command to get the file names.  The option `-print0` is used to assure that it works with difficult file names.  The `while` loop reads these file names one by one, into the variable `fname`.  `fname` includes the full path to the source file. The file name without the path is then stored in `new`.  Then two checks are performed.  If the source file is already in the current directory, the script continues on to the next loop.  Similarly, if the file name id `.DS_Store`, it is also skipped.  (The `find` command, as given, already skips these files. This line is there just for future flexibility.)  Next, the file name is split into two parts: the `name` and `ext`, the extension.  `ext` includes the leading period.  Next, a loop checks for files of the form name.NNN.ext and stops at the first one that doesn't yet exist.   The source file is moved to a file of that name.

#### Related Notes Regarding the GNU Solution and its Compatibility

- Quoting in the above GNU command is complex.  The argument to `bash -c` needs to be in single-quotes to prevent the calling bash from performing premature variable substitution.  In addition, the  `sed` commands need to be in single-quotes when executed by the bash subshell to prevent history expansion from interfering with the use of negation, `!`, within the `sed` command.
- The OSX (BSD) `sed` does not support combining commands together with semicolons.  Consequently, each command is supplied to `sed` via a separate `-e` option.
- The OSX (BSD) `sed` seems to treat `+` differently from the GNU `sed`.  This incompatibility seems to go away when using the `-E` (extended regex) option.  (The corresponding GNU option is `-r` but, as an undocumented compatibility feature, GNU `sed` supports `-E` also.

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, it did not help: the random text still appears after the extension. Here's a sample output:
./0/A/1/IMG_0002.PNG -> ./IMG_0002.PNG.VRI
Also: should I be including the "\" in: bash -c \ 'mv… (Works either way).

Comment: @natkoy I just copied from the answer to my shell and tried it again and it works for me.  However, I see that you are on OSX and the utilities there often operate a little bit.  I just updated the answer with a version that I hope is OSX-compatible.     If it doesn't work, _let me know the __exact__ error message_.  Separately, the backslash was just to allow the command to be written on two lines for readability.  To avoid confusion, I removed it from the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you again John. Sorry but that didn't do it. I made bash verbose and here's the output from one instance:
`mv -v "$1" "./$(mktemp -u "$(basename "$1" | sed "s/\.\([^.]\+\)$/.XXX.\1/; /XXX/ !s/$/.XXX/")" )"
mktemp -u "$(basename "$1" | sed "s/\.\([^.]\+\)$/.XXX.\1/; /XXX/ !s/$/.XXX/")" 
basename "$1" | sed "s/\.\([^.]\+\)$/.XXX.\1/; /XXX/ !s/$/.XXX/"
./A/001.jpg -> ./001.jpg.qzH`

Comment: And here's the result of your sed echo when running it inside a subdir:
`echo 001.jpg | sed -e "s/\.\([^.]\+\)$/.XXX.\1/" -e "/XXX/ !s/$/.XXX/"
-bash: !s/$/.XXX/": event not found`

Comment: @natkoy "_event not found_"  That is helpful information.  You have history expansion turned on and, as a result, bash is treating the exclamation point as an active character.  If you are not using history expansion, I recommend turning it off just to avoid issues like this:  `set +H`.   Then try `echo 001.jpg | sed -e "s/\.\([^.]\+\)$/.XXX.\1/" -e "/XXX/ !s/$/.XXX/"`  If you want to keep history expansion, we can do that but it will make the quoting issues a bit more complex.

Comment: @natkoy I have added a line the the answer with the more complex coding so as to avoid history expansion.  Let me know how it works.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help! Sadly, I'm still getting the random string **after** the extension (regardless of whether I use your simple option and set history expand off, or if I use the history expansion friendly one. Running the test echo command gives me: 001.jpg.XXX
Note: for OS X, the command to switch history expand off is `set +o histexpand` (and I can check whether it's on/off with `set -o`)

Comment: @natkoy Please try `echo filename.ext | sed -e 's/\.\([^.]\+\)$/.XXX.\1/' -e '/XXX/ !s/$/.XXX/'` and let me know the _exact_ error message.

Comment: Thx again for your help. I tried what you asked + variations but I still only get: filename.ext.XXX (but no errors).

Comment: @natkoy  That is frustrating.  I have no access to a Mac or BSD system to test these on.  If you still have patience, try: (a) `echo filename.ext | sed -E -e 's/\.([^.]+)$/.XXX.\1/' -e '/XXX/ !s/$/.XXX/'` and (b) `echo filename.ext | sed -E -e 's/\.([[:alnum:]]+)$/.XXX.\1/' -e '/XXX/ !s/$/.XXX/'`

Comment: HOORAY! So not only do both of the last ones work, but they also seem to work with history expansion on or off. Thank you for your persistance! I'll let you rework your answer and mark it as such when it's done.

Comment: Addendum to my previous reply: actually… both seem to only work if there are no more than 2 instances of a file with an identical name; if there are more than 2 than the third instance gets overwritten:
`mktemp: mkstemp failed on 0004.XXX.jpg: File exists   
./B/0004.jpg -> ./0004.jpg`

Comment: @natkoy I tried it with one thousands files of the same name and there was no problem.  I am guessing that the problem you see is caused by mktemp failing to handle concurrent executions properly.  Please try one or both of the approaches shown in the section entitled "File name collisions".

Comment: Thx again! Sadly, neither works (histexpand is still set to off). In both cases here's a sample output line (removed `echo` from option #1): `mktemp: mkstemp failed on 0004.XXX.jpg: File exists    ./B/0004.jpg -> ./0004.jpg` I always get "XXX" instead of a random XYZ. Could it be my settings? Here's a recap of what's on/off: `ON: braceexpand, emacs, hashall, history, interactive-comments, monitor; OFF: allexport, errexit, errtrace, functrace, histexpand, ignoreeof, keyword, noclobber, noexec, noglob, nolog, notify, nounset, onecmd, physical, pipefail, posix, privileged, verbose, vi, xtrace`

Comment: I did some digging and it looks like mktemp is different in OS X. See [this page](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30091/fix-or-alternative-for-mktemp-in-os-x)

Comment: @natkoy You are right!  According to the [OSX mktemp man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mktemp.1.html), it supports only trailing XXX.  I will have to think of another workaround..........

Comment: @natkoy Just to verify, would you run `mktemp -u filename.XXX.ext` and tell me what it returns?

Comment: @natkoy OK.  That verifies that the OSX `mktemp` is really not usable here.  I will think of a workaround.

Comment: Godspeed! Time to be resourceful…

Comment: @natkoy  Try the new version.

Comment: Awesome — it works! Good going! One thing you might want to explain and/or that I'm curious about. Since in this instance I'm running the script with . as the working directory, how come it doesn't rename the script itself?

Comment: @natkoy The line  `[ "$fname" = "./$new" ] && continue` prevents that.  In other words, if the new file and the old file have the same name, then `continue` is executed.  The `continue` statement in bash, like in other languages, means jump back to the top of the loop and start over with the next value (next `fname`).

Comment: Thanks for all your help! FYI regarding my last question I meant more specifically how come the **script file** (that's in the same directory) doesn't get renamed/moved/affected?

Comment: @natkoy If my previous reply didn't answer it, please clarify: What "script file" that is in what "same directory"?

Comment: The .sh file (I'm running the actual script using "." to find the files to be moved and renamed). Just curious why it doesn't move and rename the actual script.

Comment: @natkoy It is the line `[ "$fname" = "./$new" ] && continue` which prevents that.  It causes any file which is already in the current directory, `./`, to be skipped (not moved).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying; and thanks again for your great work and persistence.